# Where to make an Initial AJAX request from in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, frontend, reactjs

I have a page where I need to load some initial Ajax data.
I read on this `Reactjs` [page](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) that I should make the call in `componentDidMount`.
What is the **advantage** of making the request from `componentDidMount` rather than `componentWillMount` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since react is meant to be used as a view, your ajax requests are supposed to be placed in your model.

Else, if for some reason you need to make it in a view, the difference between `componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount` is that the first one is being invoked **once** the element is re-rendered and you have access to it via `this.getDOMNode()`, and the second one is invoked **once** right before `render()` starts.

Comment: What if I dont want to mess with the node. Just `setState` ?

Comment: As we manually render in the second method, so will `setState` automatically do it for us in the first method.. Won't it ?

Comment: The React docs recommend sending ajax requests in [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount): "If you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks, set timers using setTimeout or setInterval, or send AJAX requests, perform those operations in this method."

Comment: @myusuf the `componentWillMount` method is only called once, whereas `componentDidMount` is being invoked each time the component is re-rendered. So if you want to load some initial data you can do it  in `componentWillMount`. But in case you want to load some data again and again as component changes it's state you should use `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Removed odd lines from answer above.

Comment: "componentDidMount is being invoked each time the component is re-rendered." <-- This is false. componentDidUpdate is called each time the component is re-rendered; componentDidMount is called only once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So from what I gather, would it be safe to say that there is no exclusive advantage of `componentDidMount` over `componentWillMount`, except for if we need to use `getDOMNode` ?

Answer (score 7):

When using server rendering, `componentWillMount` is called but `componentDidMount` is not. Because of this, I tend to do any initialization that requires a browser (including Ajax and DOM manipulation) in `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 4):

In `componentDidMount()` you have access to the DOM if you need it; in `componentWillMount()` you don't yet have access (although you may not need it if all you want to do is call `setState`).

Make sure that in your `render()` method you're capable of gracefully rendering the "empty" state (ie. before the Ajax results have arrived back). `getInitialState()` can be helpful here for setting up some base empty state.